# Unable to access wordpress page

Tags: templates, errors

Website link:
http://belmont.perth.anglican.org/

error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in
>   /home/belmont.perth.anglican.org/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/photo-gallery/framework/WD_BWG_Theme.php
>   on line 1092

Hi, i am new to wordpress. The page was working for a few months. Recently receive this error message. Does anyone know how to reset the template for the page. i dont mind starting from zero. it is for a church website? thanks

cheers
angeline

Comment: Hi fellow West Australian. I checked if your wp-admin was available for login and it wasn't due to the error. Do you have access to the back-end database through a tool such phpmyadmin or similar. You might have to disable the photo gallery plugin manually. Junaid's answer should also get you going again.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in the plugin **[Photo Gallery](https://wordpress.org/plugins/photo-gallery/)** that your site is using. In order to fix this, you'll have to deactivate or delete this plugin. In order to deactivate or delete this plugin, please follow the following steps:

1. Log in to your website's cPanel or use FTP to access your website's files.
2. Navigate to `/wp-content/plugins/`
3. Look for directory called `photo-gallery` and rename it to something else.

Now, that faulty plugin will be deactivated and your website should work properly considering nothing else is broken.

To get back the gallery plugin, I recommend you backup and delete the directory you just renamed. Then go to `/wp-admin` of your website > Plugins > New and search for "Photo Gallery by 10Web". Install the plugin with title "Photo Gallery by 10Web – Mobile-Friendly Image Gallery" and you should have your gallery plugin back.

While doing so, I recommend you update all the plugins and the core WordPress while you are at it. To do so:

1. Backup your website.
2. Go to `/wp-admin/` > Dashboard > Updates to update WordPress, plugins and themes.

I hope this will solve your issues and if you have any questions regarding this solution, you can ask in comments to this answer.